# Rails Devise disable or remove user registration but keep user edit path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to disable user registration path and keep user edit path. I used this guide [for devise Solution 2.](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-edit-their-password)

But I am getting this error

```
 ActionController::UnknownFormat at /users.55840776527573104d0c0000
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

The form generates incorrect url, it should be like that

```
/users/55840776527573104d0c0000
```

View

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: user_registration_path(resource), html: { method: :patch}) do |f| %>


<%= f.submit "Update"%>
```

routes.rb

```
 devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]
  as :user do
    get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
    patch'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
  end
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Could you please post the routes file plus the link in your view?

Comment: Just added routes.rb and form. It is as in Devise guide.

Comment: I am working on Devise as well, but I can't help you with this (yet!). Out of curiosity: why did you change the `put` (as it is in the Devise guide) to `patch` ?

Comment: It says in the Devise guide - "If you using Rails 4.x - change put to patch"

Answer (score 3):

Solution for this problem is to add `:id` into routes.rb - patch

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]
  as :user do
    get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'
    patch'users/:id' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'
  end
```

Found solution [here](http://onrails.club/t/rails-devise-ubrat-sign-up-no-ostavit-edit-path/457/2)